# Is there a linux command to copy a file to multiple other files based on the filename?

Tags: centos, file-copy

Is there a Linux command to copy `a_b_c_d.jpg` into `a.jpg`, `b.jpg`, `c.jpg`, and  `d.jpg` so that each file is a copy of the original?

It should extract the name from the original name, separated by `_` and ending with the first `.`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'split' a file? Do you want to split its name or the content?

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and then learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I only want to split the name. Basically it should duplicate the file.

Comment: Please past text as text. So we can all read it.

Comment: Looks to me, like your trying to remove the preceding garbage infront of the original A12345_lifestyle.jpg filenames. Is this correct?

Comment: Take a look at using "find" and perhaps have a script run in the "-exec" when a filename match is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mayhap something along this line:

```
for FN in *.jpg; do IFS="_."; AR=($FN); for i in "${AR[@]}"; do [ ! "$i" = "jpg" ] &&  echo cp "$FN" "$i".jpg; done; done
cp a_b_c_d.jpg a.jpg
cp a_b_c_d.jpg b.jpg
cp a_b_c_d.jpg c.jpg
cp a_b_c_d.jpg d.jpg
```

You may want to add some more error checking, IFS safe guarding, remove the `echo` once you're happy with it, etc...

**EDIT**ed according to Kusalananda's comment.

```
for FN in *.jpg; do IFS="_"; for i in ${FN%.jpg}; do echo cp "$FN" "$i".jpg; done; done
```

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks. I Like your `%.jpg` approach - makes it much simpler. Should have thought of it...

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

for name in *_*.jpg; do
    # Only care about regular files
    [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue

    # Do the following in a subshell to avoid affecting the original 
    # environment with "set -f" and setting IFS
    (
        set -f    # Turn off filename globbing (allows filename to contain e.g. *)
        IFS='_'   # Split unquoted strings on "_" only

        # Split the filename into parts (remove trailing ".jpg" first), and then
        # iterate over the parts, creating the symbolic links
        for part in ${name%.jpg}; do
            ln -s -- "$name" "$part.jpg"

            # To do copying instead, use:
            # cp -i -- "$name" "$part.jpg"
        done
    )
done
```

This script would iterate over all filenames that contain at least one underscore and that ends with `.jpg` in the current directory.  For each such name, it would split the name on underscores and create *symbolic links* to the original file (rather than copies) from the parts of the split up name (with the `.jpg` filename suffix added).

I opted for creating symbolic links rather than real copies of the original files as that would not use use up too much additional disk space. If you really wanted to do copies, then the code for that is found in a comment in the script.

Running this in a directory with the two files `a_b_c_d.jpg` and `ABBA_hello there_misc.jpg` would produce

```
.
|-- ABBA.jpg -> ABBA_hello there_misc.jpg
|-- ABBA_hello there_misc.jpg
|-- a.jpg -> a_b_c_d.jpg
|-- a_b_c_d.jpg
|-- b.jpg -> a_b_c_d.jpg
|-- c.jpg -> a_b_c_d.jpg
|-- d.jpg -> a_b_c_d.jpg
|-- hello there.jpg -> ABBA_hello there_misc.jpg
`-- misc.jpg -> ABBA_hello there_misc.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to...

```
for x in a b c d
do
  cp a_b_c_d.jpg $x.jpg
done
```

I'd hazard a guess that you want to do this more programmatically though and not have to specify the `a b c d` part but take it from the filename.

If this is the case then you will want to take the filename and split it twice, first based on the occurrence of `.` to get the file extension, and then again based on `_` to get the filenames.  This can be done using [IFS](https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-split-string/) and the looping over the array of filenames as I have done in the above original example.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wrote simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in *_*.jpg; do
   n=$(echo "$filename" | awk -F '_' '{print NF}')
   for ((i=1; i<$n;i++)) ;do
      cp "$filename" "$(echo "$filename" | awk -F '_' '{print '"\$$i"'}')".jpg
   done
   cp "$filename" "$(echo "$filename" | awk -F '_' '{print '"\$$n"'}')"
done
```

It will search for all `jpg` files having atleast one`_`. Then using `cp "$filename" "$(echo "$filename" | awk -F '_' '{print '"\$$i"'}')".jpg` it will copy original file. However the last argument contains `.jpg` extension, so I wrote that separately outside for loop without `.jpg`. extension.